# PowerShell until step in loop

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a script that will update Windows with PSWindowsUpdate. I want the script to continually run PSWindowsUpdate until there are no more updates left to install. The script fails on the last 'until' command indicating:

```
until : The term 'until' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\user\Desktop\Install-WindowsUpdates-Edit.ps1:63 char:2
+ } until ($updates -eq $null)
+   ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (until:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

There's an until a few lines above with no problems. All of the brackets I can see are completed with an `{}` each. I don't understand why this error is happening.

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
This script will automatically install all avaialable windows updates on a device and will automatically reboot if needed, after reboot, windows updates will continue to run until no more updates are available. Pilfered     from: https://www.altaro.com/msp-dojo/powershell-windows-updates/#comment-272
#>

"Installing NuGet Package Provider"

Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force

"Installing the PSWindowsUpdate module"

Install-Module PSWindowsUpdate -Force

# retrieves a list of available updates
"Checking for new updates"

$updates = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Get-WUList -Verbose}

# counts how many updates are available
$updatenumber = ($updates.kb).Count

# if there are available updates proceed with installing the updates and then reboot
if ($updates -ne $null) {
    # Command to install windows updates, creates a scheduled task on the computer
    $Script = {
        Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate;
        Get-WindowsUpdate -AcceptAll -Install | Out-File C:\PSWindowsUpdate.log
    }

    Invoke-WUJob -Script $Script -Confirm:$false -RunNow

    # Show update status until the amount of installed updates equals the same as the amount of updates available

    sleep -Seconds 30

    do {
        $updatestatus = Get-Content c$\PSWindowsUpdate.log

        "Currently processing the following update:"
        Get-Content c$\PSWindowsUpdate.log | select-object -last 1

        sleep -Seconds 10

        $ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
        $installednumber = ([regex]::Matches($updatestatus, "Installed" )).Count
        $ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
    } until ($installednumber -eq $updatenumber)

    # restarts the remote computer and waits till it starts up again

    "restarting computer"

    Restart-Computer -Wait -Force
} until ($updates -eq $null) #ERROR THROWN HERE

# removes schedule task from computer
#Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName PSWindowsUpdate -Confirm:$false}

Remove-Module -Name "PSWindowsUpdate"

"Windows is now up to date"
```

Comment: I can see 2 `until` statemants, but only *1* `do`!? Seems like your code is simply faulty.

Comment: The `}` right curly bracket in `}until ($updates -eq $null) #ERROR THROWN HERE` closes the script block starting at `if ($updates -ne $null){` (not expected `do {`).

Comment: If you indent your code properly you would be able to see the mistake yourself..

Comment: I had it indented but had to nix that because of the page's editor. @marsze's statement is correct. I'm missing a { just have to find it.

Comment: JosefZ already explained what the error is, and it's not a missing `{`.

Comment: From a quick look, `until ($updates -eq $null)` should be removed and `if ($updates -ne $null)` replaced by `while ($updates -ne $null)`.